# iframe + instanceof Object FAIL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, iframe, microsoft-edge

This blew my mind today, check it out:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>framed</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="sandbox2.html" frameborder="0" width="640" height="480" id="frame"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

sandbox2.html (insides of the iframe)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>instanceof Object FAIL DEMO</h1>
    <div id="foo"></div>
    #foo.bar instanceof Object: <span id="result"></span>
    <br/>
    typeof #foo.bar: <span id="result2"></span>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            document.getElementById('foo').bar = { test: 'aaa' };
            setInterval(function() {
                document.getElementById('result').textContent = (document.getElementById('foo').bar instanceof Object).toString();
                document.getElementById('result2').textContent = (typeof document.getElementById('foo').bar).toString();
            }, 100);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, open index.html, go to the developer console and type

```
document.getElementById("frame").contentDocument.getElementById('foo').bar = {}
```

`typeof #foo.bar` returns `object` (and foo is actually an Object)

But `#foo.bar instanceof Object` returns **false!!!!**

I've tried Chrome, Firefox and MS Edge, all have the same behavior. Why is this happening? Is this some kind of bug?

Comment: what does `#foo.bar instanceof Object` mean in real javascript

Comment: `document.getElementById('foo').bar instanceof Object`

it's right there in sandbox2.html

Comment: when I create two files like you did, the output is `#foo.bar instanceof Object: true` 
`typeof #foo.bar: object ` - is that what you expected?

Comment: Yes that is what I expected, but did you call

`document.getElementById("frame").contentDocument.getElementById('foo').bar = {}`

from the console in `index.html`?

Comment: that's because it's no longer an instance of [window.]Object - it's an instance of parent.Object

Comment: Ok, so an Object in the iframe is a different type than Object outside of the iframe? That sounds reasonable.

Comment: not only is it reasonable, it's obvious :p

Comment: Obvious once you know it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change sandbox2.html to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>instanceof Object FAIL DEMO</h1>
    <div id="foo"></div>
    #foo.bar instanceof Object: <span id="result"></span>
    <br/>
    #foo.bar instanceof parent.Object: <span id="result1"></span>
    <br/>
    typeof #foo.bar: <span id="result2"></span>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            document.getElementById('foo').bar = { test: 'aaa' };
            setInterval(function() {
                document.getElementById('result').textContent = (document.getElementById('foo').bar instanceof Object).toString();
                document.getElementById('result1').textContent = (document.getElementById('foo').bar instanceof parent.Object).toString();
                document.getElementById('result2').textContent = (typeof document.getElementById('foo').bar).toString();
            }, 100);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you will see that changing, from the main frame, the object in the iframe will change it from an instanceOf Object to an instanceOf parent.Object - the two are different Objects